# I was not able to call edit function in below function return statement

Tags: javascript, html, function

**Can we call edit Js function onclick..?**

```
fuction edit() {
alert("Hi");
}

function drawButton() {
return'<a href="#" onclick="edit();"><img src="abc.jpg"></a>';
}
```

Comment: you mean after rendring and on click on image abc.jpg ? if yes the response will be you can too

Comment: Could you provide some context and more code?

Comment: there is spelling mistake, instead of `fuction edit() {` write `function edit() {`

Comment: something else first needs to call the `drawButton()` function, and then render the results of that function to the DOM. Does that part work?

Comment: yes here nly it was spel mistake but in my code it was good

Comment: but the edit function not triggring while onclick...